# Cross partial with implicit differentiation

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem

For some $x$ defined by an implicit function, i'm interested in how $\frac{\partial x}{\partial k}$ changes with $x$. Is this simply

$$\frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial k \partial x}$$

Or does this not make sense?

Comment: Do you want to derivate $\frac{\partial x}{\partial k}$ with respect to $x$?

Comment: @botond Yes, that's right.

Comment: That would be $\frac{\partial^2x}{\partial x\partial k}=\frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial k \partial x}$ (with Young's theorem)

Comment: Ah of course. But does it make sense to differentiate in terms of $x$? Since $x$ is the differentiand (i.e. the term in the numerator)?

Answer (score 0):

Let $x:=k^2+p^2$. Then:
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial k}=2k$$
Now derivate it with respect to $x$:
$$\frac{\partial(2k)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial(2k)}{\partial k}\frac{\partial k}{\partial x}=2\frac{\partial k}{\partial x}$$
So I think it makes sense.